# how to use datePicker() plugin in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

In reference to the site  "

- http://www.kelvinluck.com/assets/jquery/datePicker/v2/demo/datePickerClickInput.html

", i used the datePicker() plugin of jquery. But its not working for me!!
I've updated my codings in

- http://jsfiddle.net/9L7kE/7/

. Kindly help!!!. Thanks in advance

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/9L7kE/22/   You are using datePicker then datepicker, not refereencing jquery.Ui and two document ready

Answer (score 0):

in js fiddle you have:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(function() {
        $( "#date_picker" ).datePicker({clickInput:true});
        });
});
```

​

**$(function_to_tun)** is the same as **$(document).ready(function_to_tun)**

adding a onready event after the event was fired will not not fire it again so you just need to use only one of the 2

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $( "#date_picker" ).datePicker({clickInput:true});
});
```

or

```
$(function() {
    $( "#date_picker" ).datePicker({clickInput:true});
});
```

and also don't forget to add the librarys

Comment: i used the first option, still not working for me. What is the library files u r talking abt.I'm a total fresher and not able to understand too technical jargons. Pls help!!! The codings in jsfiddle r updated, but still its not working.

Answer (score 0):

Use this one. It's very easy to use.

http://keith-wood.name/datepick.html

Comment: i downloaded the entire zip file and after extraction, tried in my system, its not working. What would be issue. Can u pls guess it. Pls help me on the same.

Comment: 1- You have not included date picker css file.
2- You have incorrect path to js and css files
3- You may have forgot to inclde jquery (framework) file (js).

Comment: where will i  get these files?

Comment: thnks. though ur answers were not so useful for me as a fresher..I got the soluion. its working fine for me now!